# Select/paste popup disappears on iOS 8 Safari when DOM is updated

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a textarea where users can edit text. On the same page I have a clock that updates every second in an interval. I use the jQuery text() function to alter the displayed time in the clock. Whenever the clock updates, any open native iOS select & paste popup immediately disappears. This happens in iPad with iOS 8.1 Safari. Does anyone know of a solution to this issue?